# iOS9: After restarting my test device, Universal Links do not work any more

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, ios-universal-links

I have read several QA about "Universal Links do not work" or "How to set up Universal Links on iOS9". I configured my server and domain correctly and successfully invoked this feature.

My development environment is: Xcode 7.3.0(7D157), an iPhone 6(A1586), iOS 9.3.5.

But after restarting my test device (the iPhone), the Universal Links does not work any more. I notice that my iPhone can't recognize my app after that. The system seems consider that my app is not installed at all. When I long pressed an URL in the note app, the action sheet pop from bottom does not contain the lines of "open in myApp" or "open in Safari".

That's why I say the system can't recognize my app. However it just occur after  restarting my iPhone.

Now, I have to re-compile and re-build my project to invoke this feature each time after restart. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14558

by adding '/' to solve this : )

```
{
 "applinks": {  
     "apps": [],   
     "details": {  
          "<app_id>.stuff":{  
               "paths": [ "*", "/" ]  
          }  
     }  
  }   
}
```

or to validate apple-app-site-association through this:

https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/